# Can I delete a snapshot once an EBS volume has been created

Tags: amazon-ec2, snapshot

If I have an EBS volume, say A, I make a snapshot from it, then create a new EBS volume B from that snapshot. Can I delete the snapshot right away?

Or do I have to wait that all the blocks are copied from S3? If so, how do I figure that out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can. I just created a 500GB volume from an existing snapshot and I deleted the snapshot right after that.

I'm not sure what Amazon does internally but they probably have some redundant replication mechanism that allows you to delete the snapshot right away (Maybe it's Xen which the AWS virtual infrastructure is based of off originally, although they have a highly customized Xen setup)

One way to test it is with a python script as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import boto

conn = boto.connect_ec2()
Snapshots = conn.get_all_snapshots()
# Snapshots[0] is the first snapshot in your account
# User the one you want to use to create the volume
conn.create_volume("8", "us-east-1b", Snapshots[0])
conn.delete_snapshot(Snapshots[0].id)
```